# Where does file information (like DateCreated) get stored when you create a new file?

Tags: c#, io

Suppose that I would like to add extra information *about* a file, without writing that information as *content of* that file. How would I do this? A couple of good examples are:

1. With Word documents, you can add Author tag to a document. And,
2. MP3 files have lots of info stored inside of them but when you play the file, you don't see that info (unless the program playing the file has been programmed to display that information).

How does Windows do this?

Comment: In fact, in those two specific cases the data is part of the file. See details here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information is stored in the file system (on windows - NTFS). 
In NTFS, you can actually store another file, as part of this information, and it stores much more information about each file than you may expected.

[NTFS file streams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364404%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Exapmle in C how to consume them](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/105763)

About MP3 and word - In these cases the information is stored inside the file, as part of its format.

Comment: if this information is stored in the NTFS file system on Windows, then how does Linux know when this file was created when I copy and paste this same file onto a new computer running a different OS? That makes me think that this information is stored inside the actual file?

Comment: No. Some file attributes exist on virtually any file system (such as size, date created, and date modified) - so when you copy file from different FS, those attributes are copied with it. Other attributes are unique to specific FS's, so they won't be copied from supporting FS, to a one that does not support them (such as alternate filestreams, which are unique to NTFS).